# java script rename the attribute name in array of tree objects

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, axios

I need to  rename "text" attribute with "name" in all of objects (parent and child)
the API return the objects as below:

```js
"content": [
  [{
    "id": 1,
    "text": "hierarchy 1",
    "icon": "h",
    "children": [{
        "id": 2,
        "text": "hierarchy 11",
        "icon": "h",
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "text": "hierarchy 110",
        "icon": "h",
        "children": []
      }
    ]
  }]
]
```

My API function should return the same result but after rename "text" with "name":

```
  async getTree() {
    const res = await axios.get("/api/HierarchyTree");
    return res.data.content["0"].map(item => {
      return {
        ...item,
        name: item.text
      };
    });

  }
```

The result should be:

```js
"content": [

  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "hierarchy 1",
    "icon": "h",
    "children": [{
        "id": 2,
        "name": "hierarchy 11",
        "icon": "h",
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "hierarchy 110",
        "icon": "h",
        "children": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this?

```js
let  content = [
  [{
    "id": 1,
    "text": "hierarchy 1",
    "icon": "h",
    "children": [{
        "id": 2,
        "text": "hierarchy 11",
        "icon": "h",
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "text": "hierarchy 110",
        "icon": "h",
        "children": []
      }
    ]
  }]
]
content = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(content[0]).replace(/"text"/g,'"name"'))
console.log(content)
```